# AngularJs template url loading throws CORS error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I have developed an app using AngularJS.

It is live at the following url but it isn't working because of CORS issue on loading templates:
http://www.ebust.it/app/#/lines/list

The app works fine on the url without "www":
http://ebust.it/app/#/lines/list

The error that I get from js console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ebust.it/themes/frontend/spa/app/views/lines.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.ebust.it' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I also tried to force the template as absolute URL. Have you ever experiences something similar? I can't understand why Angular is using the wrong domain to perform the AJAX request for the template URL.

Comment: Perhaps [MDN: Changing Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin). But, `ebust.it` and `www.ebust.it` are distinct hostnames and [origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). So, they don't inherently have access to each other client-side.

Comment: Do you mind providing some of the relevant Angular code?

Comment: I agree with you. I need AngularJS to use the same host as the one of the browser window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$http` Ajax requests become cross-origin when requests for the scripts are redirected:

```
<script src="/themes/frontend/spa/app/scripts/controllers/line.js"></script>
```

```sh
curl -v http://www.ebust.it/themes/frontend/spa/app/scripts/services/line.js
...
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
...
< Location: http://ebust.it/themes/frontend/spa/app/scripts/services/line.js
...
```

Each script is tied to is the origin that serves it, `http://ebust.it/`, rather than that of the document, `http://www.ebust.it/`.

To resolve this, you could:

- Serve the scripts from both origins rather than redirecting.
- Specify the hostname that serves the scripts in the Ajax URLs:

  ```
  return $http({
      // ...
      url: '//ebust.it/line/georeverse'
  });
  ```
- Adjust the origin with [`document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin).

  ```
  document.domain = 'ebust.it';
  ```

  ```
  url: '//' + document.domain + '/line/georeverse'
  ```
- Or configure CORS to allow the requests between the 2 origins.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Your answer helped me to figure out what's happening. I can't believe that a simple alias on Apache vhost can break an AngularJS app. These steps should be documented somewhere. Anyway, I had to apply the last two bullets together to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried relative URLs instead of absolute ones? What are you using for routing? ui-router? Ideally if you're using ngRouter or ui-router, if you give relative paths, this will not cause CORS issues. CORS comes into picture only if you give absolute (and incorrect i.e. belonging to a different domain) URL

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.hostname` or the Angular way `$location.host()` to get the appropriate "www.ebust.it" or "ebust.it" and load the template by concatenating the path to the host.

Comment: It doesn't work. I've already tried this way. AngularJS keeps doing request using ebust.it as hostname instead of www.ebust.it