# AngularJS, Localhost, and CORS errors when loading a template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I am attempting to load a template using Angular's ui-router.

index.html

```
<html ng-app="someApp">
<body ng-controller='SomeCtrl'>
        <div ui-view>
        </div>
</body>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('someApp', [])

.config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
      .state('someApp', {
        url:"/",
        templateUrl: 'app/things/things.tmpl.html',
        controller: 'SomeCtrl'
      })
  })
```

When I attempt to go to the root of the application in localhost (dragging and dropping the html file into the browser) I get a CORS error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://localhost/Users/me/theApp/src/app/things/things.tmpl.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

The url in my browser window and the url in the error seem to be one in the same. Is it because Angular uses an HTTP request to fetch the template as indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616126/angularjs-template-url-loading-throws-cors-error)? They don't seem to be analogous problems, as there shouldn't be a different domain besides localhost serving the template.

Comment: Chrome won't allow you to load files like that, you will need to serve up your application in a server (apache, node, python, IIS, something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep 100% need at least a local server running. MAMP is probably the easiest. http://www.mamp.info/en/

Do a Mac install and then put the app root in the /Applications/Mamp/htdocs folder. Then it's by default localhost:8888/app-name/ when Mamp is open and running.

Answer (score 1):

@Tom was exactly right--you can't load files in Chrome that way. I had to start an http server.

I followed [these directions](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed#running-the-app-during-development) to install http-server and start a server using:

```
http-server -a localhost -p 8000
```

This allowed the app and my templates to load correctly.